# Upload speed inside Docker Container is limited to 4 Mbit/s

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I am new to dockers and I have a docker container running for a set of students with some version-specific compilers and it's a part of a virtual laboratory setup.

Everything is fine with the setup except for the network. I have a 200 Mbps network and this is a speed test done on my phone on the same 200 Mbps network.

[image: Speedtest on iPhone XR]

I did a speed test on the host machine where the docker container is running. It is running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It is all good.

[image: speedtest on host]

From inside the docker container running on the above host machine, I did a speed test with the same server ID 9898 and with an auto-selected server too.

[image: speedtest inside container]

**We can see that the upload speed inside the docker container is limited to 4 Mbit/s somehow. I cannot find a reason why elsewhere.**

I have seen recently that many students experienced connection drops during their attempt to connect to our SSH server. I believe this has something to do with the bandwidth limit.

The `docker run` command I am using to run this container build is as follows.

```
$ sudo docker run -p 7766:22 --detach --name lahtp-serv-3 --hostname lahtp-server --mount source=lahtp-3-storage-hdd,target=/var/lahtp-storage main:0.1
```

I asked a few people who suggested to run the container with `net=host` which will run the container with the host network instead of the docker network. I would like to know why docker container limits the upload bandwidth and how using the host network instead of the docker network fixes the issue?

**Update #1:**

I tried to spawn a new Ubuntu 18.04 container with the following command:

```
$ sudo docker run --net=host -it ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash
```

Once inside the container, I installed the following to run the speedtest.

```
root@lahtp-server:/# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install build-essential openssh-server speedtest-cli
```

Once the installation is done, here is the results.

[image]

But adding `--net=host` does not change the issue. The upload speed is still 4 Mbit/s

How to remove this bandwidth throttling?

**Update #2**

I spawned a new Ubuntu 14.04 docker container using the following command

```
$ sudo docker run -it ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Once the container is up, I installed the following

```
$ apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip
$ pip3 install speedtest-cli
```

And tested inside this container, and here are the results.
NO THROTTLING.

[image]

Did the same with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, No throttling.

```
$ sudo docker run -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

And once inside the container

```
$ apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip
$ pip3 install speedtest-cli
```

[image]
NO THROTTLING.

Comment: That's interesting. I suggest to post this on Docker issues on GitHub too. https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues

Comment: I wonder if this limit is caused by docker or the combination of docker with `speedtest` program. What if you run a ftp server somewhere and upload something from inside a container? Is it still limited to 4Mbps?

Comment: @AliTou - I am trying that now.

Comment: @AliTou - Your analogy about the combination of docker and speedtest program might be true. Will update here soon.

Comment: I guess the pip3 installation of `speedtest-cli` is doing fine but the apt-get version of `speedtest-cli` is showing the throttled speed inside docker.

Comment: Do the versions differ? You can check the apt one with `apt-cache policy speedtest-cli` and pip one with `pip3 freeze | grep speedtest`.